# Manifest Merger tools:replace doesnt have any effect

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

Im using image-chooser-library in my app, which has android:icon defined so i need to override this attribute for gradle to build successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sample.sample">

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
         tools:replace="icon"/>

</manifest>
```

But still im getting the following:

**Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@drawable/icon) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:9
    is also present at com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.4.3:13:9 value=(@drawable/ic_launcher)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5 to override**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and because it happened on multiple build machines and when creating a test project with just the library causing the issue, everything worked fine, I was suspecting some bug in manifest merging tool.

I fixed it by changing the order of dependencies in gradle file (the library causing the issue was the last in list and I moved it on top).

Comment: tried everything, and this is what worked for me in the end! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. This definitely the solution when tools:replace doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Thousand times of Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `useOldManifestMerger true` in your build.gradle file (in `android{}` tag), but this feature is remove from the 1.0.0 gradle plugin version.

Or add `tools:replace="android:icon"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`. (**Warnning**: you should add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in `<manifest/>` tag **at first**)

For more infomation about manifest merger, you can visit the [Official Document](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger).

Answer (score 0):

I checked it on my manifest, it's

```
tools:replace="android:icon"
```

not just `"icon"`

Comment: Tried both versions, no go.

Comment: It was worth a try, that solved it for me though... Hmm try cleaning?

Comment: @EvgeniRoitburg also try putting the tools:replace before android:icon. Just a thought...